# HTMLRenderReport of BIRT adds a `file://`-like url to embedded images (instead of embedding them into the HTML)

Tags: birt, birt-emitter

I have a BIRT report with an image in the master page.

#### My BIRT design file:

I embedded a png inside the report and it generated the following XML after the `body` tag:

```
  <list-property name="images">
      <structure>
          <property name="name">filename.png</property>
          <property name="type">image/png</property>
          <property name="data">
            BASE64 of the image
          </property>
      </structure>
   </list-property>
```

Then, I have included it into the master page, adding this element:

```
    <image id="828">
       <property name="source">embed</property>
       <property name="imageName">filename.png</property>
    </image>
```

#### Behaviours of my BIRT design file:

Then, If I run the preview from the BIRT designer it works great with both HTML and PDF output. If I render it using `IPDFRenderOption` (from my software) it generates the correct `pdf`  fine. *But* if I use `HTMLRenderOption`, then the image is not embeded into the HTML report, but it is rendered with something like:

```
 <img src="file:/.../apache-tomcat-7.0.35/design11.png">
```

#### What I expect:

While I expected something like:

```
 <img src="data:image/png;base64,BASE64 STUFF THAT I PUT IN THE LIST-PROPERTIES ">
```

So, how can I let BIRT, when executed with `HTMLRenderOption`, to embed my image into the HTML file instead of creating a link to it?

Comment: I doubt this is supported, but it would be a nice feature. In the early days when BIRT started, MSIE was the #1 browser and it didn't support <img src="data:...">

Comment: So how am I supposse to deploy a web service that produces BIRT html reports with images? Since BIRT put the local path with `file://`?

Comment: @hvb, If interested, check my workaround/solution to this problem. In contrast to other solutions in the internet, it does not involves scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding two different images to the masterpage of the report:

#### Setting of the image in the PDF output:

Since the `PDF` is well rendered, I leaved the image as I wrote in the question, and I set off the visibility of this image in the HTML output

#### Setting of the image in the HTML output:

Then, in the master page, I added a new image. This time I haven't set it as embedded. Instead I set it as referenced by an `URI`. As `URI` I set the `base64 URI` that I need in my `HTML` output. Basically, I added to the `XML` of the report the following image:

```
<image id="1972">
    <list-property name="visibility">
        <structure>
            <property name="format">pdf</property>
            <expression name="valueExpr" type="javascript">true</expression>
        </structure>
    </list-property>
        <property name="source">url</property>
        <expression name="uri" type="constant">data:image/png;base64, BASE 64 OF MY PNG IMAGE</expression>
 </image>
```

I then set the image to be visibile only for the `HTML` output.

In this way `BIRT` renders an `img` tag with the `URL` i put in the `XML`, whatever it is. And thus, it puts the `data:image/png;base64, BASE 64 OF MY PNG IMAGE` as `url`. And thus it  embeds the image in the `HTML` output.

#### Adding images from the database in your table:

BIRT supports the images inside `blob` fiels, and can manage in adding them to your report. To see how, see there: http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.birt.doc%2Fbirt%2Flayout.5.7.html

If it does not works, you can manage inserting a dynamic value on your url, still without editing the scripts (but of course using a bit of Javascript to decide which column contains the data of teh image).

Here below the XML code of an image that reads the `base64` value from a column:

```
  <image id="1974">
        <property name="source">url</property>
        <expression name="uri" type="javascript">"data:image/png;base64,"+row["BASE_64_PNG_COLUMN"]     </expression>
  </image>
```

Comment: Nice! You edited the XML directly? Would this work for dynamic images (From blobs in the DB) AS well, EG by using the DE API?

Comment: @hvb There are are standard ways to add blob-images to your report (see what I added to my answer). However, here above you can see how to do it dinamically. without complex javascript and without  `onFactory` or similar calls.

Comment: I see. This works as long as the BLOB already contains the image data base64-encoded. Otherwise, it shouldn't be too hard to create a PL/SQL function (for an Oracle DB) vor whatever to do this encoding. Nice!

Comment: Using the "data:image/png;..." approach does not work for me with BIRT 4.4.2. Firefox displays the image when pasting the full URI. But when generating PDF report (or other type) only "The resource of this report item is not reachable." instead of the image is displayed. Any ideas?

Comment: @Uli, my approach was a workaround of a render problem in the HTML rendering. The PDF render should works fine if you use the `BIRT` `<image>` tag.

Comment: Not really. I have posted a new question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30346658/birt-does-not-show-base64-encoded-image) cause I think its not solvable here. Thanks for your great idea with the base64 URIs!!